# How do I exit the Bastion of Faith?

Tags: wasteland-2

I've entered the Bastion of Faith via the Gauntlet of Samson. I helped Ascension McDade stage his coup, and installed the repeater in the radio tower. But now I can't leave.

There's a gate control, but if I try to activate it, it just goes "Stay away from the gate control, Aspirant!"

I've searched around, and there's supposed to be a secret entrance in the back of the Church of the Vigilant. I've found it (or at least I think I did, it shows up on the map in the log book), but it doesn't do anything. It says 'Examine' when I mouse over it, but nothing happens when I try to use Perception on it.

There's also a table in that room. It says there's room for me to place an object on. That might be it, but I don't know what object, and even Google won't tell me.

I can still talk to McDade, but no keywords show up, though he asks "What can I do for you". The first time I approach McDade after installing the repeater, it shows the Perception icon, but Perception doesn't do anything. Approaching him again does not show the Perception icon again.

I've looked at guides on the Internet, but they all just say to leave after installing the repeater and getting the zeolite, but they don't say how, so I'm guessing I'm missing something ridiculously trivial, but I'm stuck.

Comment: To be sure, can you get out via McDade's secret passage?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there are two ways out of there.

1. Back out of the front entrance of the Bastion - this is the heavy airlock-like gate where you had to fight some guys to prove yourself worthy first).  I have experienced some oddities regarding the front gate when I was messing around with different tactics.
2. Via a secret passage that connects a sewer entrance in Hollywood to the back wall of McDade's room.

This map shows clearly where the secret tunnel entrance in McDade's room.
http://guides.gamepressure.com/wasteland2/guide.asp?ID=27039

The entrance in Hollywood is shown on this map. It is up by a monitor on which Matthias speaks to you (and offers you a job being a very bad person).  I think it is accessible as soon as you arrive in Hollywood (i.e., not plot-locked).

If I recall correctly, when I tried to use this tunnel without first coming through from Hollywood, I was not able to do so.  That may be your issue.  If it is, then you are probably going to have to go back to a prior save to insure this passage is open first.

Another possibility is that you did not get close enough to the people in the main chamber of the Griffith Observatory after the fight was over.  That triggers a conversation which you witness between the remaining leaders.  You might be plot-locked until you witness that.

---

So, you might be asking about the perception thing.  There is a mechanism by which you can recognize [spoiler incoming]...

> a mask that is on McDade's desk that matches a description given by his prostitute lover.  This is another way to discover/confirm their relationship by confirming that he is the "broken man", but you do not need it.  Unfortunately, it seems to remain forever, creating quite a distraction for those of us that want to be sure we have seen all of the content...

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/613937306668130948/)